# Turn Neo4j into a triplestore

Tags: neo4j

I want to load a RDF file in Neo4j and turn this into a triplestore but I don't know if I can do this with the spqrl-plugin for Neo4j. I have been looking documentation for this plugin in https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/sparql-plugin, but I get 404 error when I try to open the documentation.

The thing is, Do I need to develop a program which parse a RDF file and store the tuples in Neo4j with the turtle format I desire, or there is some feature in the sparql-endpoint which allow me to perform this task easily?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea to import bulk-data into neo4j.

First convert your database into csv files and import it into Gephi - a graph visualization tool. Then by using the Gephi plugin for neo4j database support, you should be able to export your database (from Gephi) into neo4j format.

Finally just copy the exported file into appropriate neo4j directory.

For importing database into Gephi, you will need two csv files - one with all the nodes and other with all the relationships. Follow this tutorial : http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/01/fun-with-beer-and-graphs.html

Get Gephi from here: https://gephi.org/

Get the Plugin from here : https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/neo4j-graph-database-support/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily import CSV into Neo4j directly. See http://neo4j.org/develop/import

There are also several people who imported RDF files into Neo4j. http://neo4j.org/develop/linked_data

The important thing is. Develop a godo property graph model first, that you want to import your data into. You won't be happy trying to force the RDF model on a property graph and trying to query it.

There is also a presentation from Wes Freeman about importing [freebase into Neo4j](http://slid.es/wfreeman/aug-2013-meetup)

And if you want to you can reach out to http://graphalchemist.com who have also a lot of experience importing RDF into Neo4j.

But in general it is not rocket science:

1. good graph model
2. rdf parser
3. fast insertion (e.g. batch-inseter)
4. relax

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this old question needs an update.
The neosemantics (n10s) extension helps you do precisely that.
You can talk RDF to your Neo4j database, as in write triples to it and read triples from it.
Check it out [here](https://neo4j.com/labs/neosemantics/).