# Neo4j sparql plugin data loading

Tags: neo4j

I want to insert RDF data of file containing 10M triple (berlin sparql benchmark) and I want to use neo4j sparql plugin for this. I have following questions regarding this,

sort of similar question was probably asked at [Turn Neo4j into a triplestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516125/turn-neo4j-into-a-triplestore) but I couldn't find answer to my following questions.

1. Is there any other way to to load data than using  http://`localhost`:7474/db/data/ext/SPARQLPlugin/graphdb/insert_quad ? so I can query it using http://`localhost`:7474/db/data/ext/SPARQLPlugin/graphdb/execute_sparql. If there is, then how do I do it? and how do I query it after that?
2. How can I load data which is in ttl form? Do I have to have my data in quad form?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to achieve in the first place? Using Neo4j as a plain RDF store won't make you happy.

Try to look at your use-cases, create a sensible property-graph-model for those and import *into* it.

You can certainly read your ttl file with some tools or libraries available and then drive the Neo4j import from that.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks for the response. I tried loading data as shown in https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/sparql-plugin/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/server/plugin/sparql/BerlinDatasetTest.java
it worked for small files but didn't work for large file.
And
I created property graph as you suggested and according to http://michaelbloggs.blogspot.de/2013/05/importing-ttl-turtle-ontologies-in-neo4j.html 
but one of the query is really slow. For sparql data, Is creating property graph, always a good option than using neo4j as triple store?